# How to implement RDF with SPARQL in nodejs Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sparql, rdf

I am querying a sparql statement to retrieve football player names

```
var team1 = "Manchester_United_F.C.";
var query = "PREFIX p: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> " 
+"SELECT * WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/"+ team1 + "> "
+"dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract; p:manager ?manager; p:name ?player. ?player "+"dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?picture; dbpedia-owl:position ?position; "
+"dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?dob. <http://dbpedia.org/resource/" 
+ team1 
+">p:ground ?stadium. ?stadium "+
"dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?stadium_pic. filter langMatches(lang(?abstract),\"en\") }";
```

This statement is working perfectly and generating results on a web page. I want to implement rdf so that I can be redirected to wikipedia page of the football player when I click at its name or picture. Can someone guide me how do I go on doing this? 
team1 variable is different everytime so rdf data should be dynamic. I'm confused where to write this code and how to link it with the web page.

Do I need to used npm module for rdf? If yes, then how will it help me? Where do I need to write XML code for RDF?

Comment: Is there some reason to not use newlines in your code?  It makes it very hard to read.

Comment: I've edited the code now. Is it readable now?